# What do you call a number formed by a sequence of repeating digits

Tags: vocabulary, mathematics

For example, I have a sequence

```
77777777777
```

Is there a word in the dictionary to represent

> a sequence of repetitive/recurring digits

Comment: I'd call it *repetitive*

Comment: I bet someone at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would know.

Comment: I remember using 'repeating stanza' once. As jwpat says, repetend works for the repeat in a recurring decimal. It's tempting to broaden the usage, but maths is hotter on the well-defined than English per se.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you'd be re-broadening a narrowing. Generally repetend means anything that repeats *except* for numbers, because with numbers it has the more specific meaning.

Comment: Recommending migration to mathSE

Comment: Please edit to clarify if you actually mean *numbers*, or probably *digits* as in your example -- it makes a lot of difference.

Comment: Editing is supposed to be to *improve* a post, not to radically change its very essence. Please do not change the question totally by editing. You can ask a separate question. All the answers and comments up to that point will suddenly become irrelevant and the page appears ridiculous to the reader. No offense.

Answer (score 7):

This type of number is commonly called a *repdigit* number, or sometimes a *monodigit* number.  This term is used most frequently in recreational mathematics and is most often seen in investigations into prime numbers.

See [wikipedia article on repdigit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit) for details.

Comment: Apparently I saw your answer too late, and was 13 minutes behind

Comment: @LaurentDuval I do that a lot.  I post an answer before reading all of the answers only to then realise that my answer has already been given.  I shall upvote your answer because I think it is correct ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's called a *periodic sequence*. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_sequence).

Answer (score 2):

The given example is not a sequence *per se*, considering that the "digits" are not separated (by a comma, space).

A natural number whose digits are repeating in some  positional number system is called, in recreational mathematics, a [**repdigit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit). This comes from **rep**eated and digit. In the case it is composed of digit 1 (1, 11, 111, 11111), it is called a [**repunit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit). The latter was  coined  by A. H. Beiler in  1966. See [Repunit and Repdigit Numbers](http://sequencenumbers.blogspot.fr/2015/09/repunit-and-repdigit-numbers.html) for other details.

Otherwise, this would just be a c[onstant sequence](http://oeis.org/wiki/Constant_sequences):

> Constant sequences are sequences for which all terms are the same.

Answer (score 0):

*Repeating* would be the usual term, as in a *repeating decimal*, but that could also mean a sequence such as "123123123123."  If you don't mind a coinage, how about *monodigital sequence*?

Answer (score 0):

• [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/repetend) defines *repetend* as “*Mathematics* The digit or group of digits that repeats infinitely in a repeating decimal”.
• [collinsdictionary.com](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repetend) defines *repetend* as “(*mathematics*) the digit or series of digits in a recurring decimal that repeats itself”.
• [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repetend) defines *repetend* as “(*mathematics*) A repeating decimal”, which while closer to what you've asked about – ie the *sequence* of repeated numbers rather than the digits that repeat – is probably an incorrect definition.

Comment: The *decimal* is a significant part of the definition, not to be ignored.

Comment: @Kris, no it isn't.  *Decimal* is used in those definitions to direct attention to the fractional part of a number, rather than the integer part.  Repetends actually are base-agnostic; they can follow a binary point, a trinary point, etc just as well as a decimal point.

Comment: Check again. 1. It occurs **only** after the decimal point ('decimal', not binary, ternary [not trinary], etc.); 2. it repeats infinitely; 3. it need not be a single digit. *That part of a circulating decimal which recurs continually, ad infinitum: -- sometimes indicated by a dot over the first and last figures; thus, in the circulating decimal .728328328 ..., the repetend is 283.* (from the GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English)

Comment: @Kris, a repetend is a repeating element (digit or digits, possibly 0) in the representation of a fraction in a number system. Yes, the repetend repeats infinitely, but the infinite sequence that the question asks about is *not* a repetend; a repetend is merely one small but infinitely-often-repeated unit of an infinite sequence.  Re trinary vs ternary, either may be used ([1](http://paradigmsearch.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Learn-Ternary-Trinary-Base-3-mathematics),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_computer)). Re point terms, see *[Radix Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point)*

Comment: I’m so glad that everyone’s being ℚuite Rational about all this.

Comment: @tchrist, I suppose I should have said *representation of a fraction's value* instead of *representation of a fraction*.  Also, reference to ℚ is correct; a real value that isn't [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) (ie, that's in ℝ∖ℚ) can't have a repetend in spite of having an infinitely-long (non-terminating) decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

The closest single word would be *repetend*, which generally means anything that is repeated (e.g. it would also be used about music and poetry).

Unfortunately, the one thing we **cannot** use it for is repeating numbers, because it has a specific sense when it comes to numbers where it **only** refers to the repeated numbers found in representing a fraction that cannot be fully represented in the base used (e.g. ⅓ in decimal ends with a repetend of 3, 1/7 in decimal has a repetend of 142857, ⅓ in binary ends with a repetend of 01, 1/10 in binary ends with a repetend of 0011, and so on).

So, while in that one case it is the perfect word to use, in any others it is a particularly bad word to use, because it will make people think of that more specific use.

In other cases I would just use "recurring sequence" or "repeated sequence".

Comment: Interestingly, **all *ⁿ⁄₇* fractions have the same repetend** — it just starts at a different point in the sequence. When *n* is 1, it’s what you said: 142857; when *n* is 2, it’s 285714; when *n* is 3, it’s 428571; when *n* is 4, it’s 571428; when n is *5*, it’s 714285; and when *n* is 6, it’s 857142. So all you ever need to remember is a **single repetend** for all the sevenths — and how that starting point varies. １428571２8571428571４28571428５714285７142857142８571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571. . . .

Comment: @tchrist a bit beyond what I needed to express here, but if we do move this to math.SE, we'll be well-primed (excuse the pun). Meanwhile, I see a downvoter has an objection to my answer. I look forward to their explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

A **series** or **set**, maybe.

Finding an exact term for this kind of repeated number is quite hard, for it will depend on where you are currently using it